# PhpStorm object property type hint

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, type-hinting

I'm using type hinting in PhpStorm in `.php` files which works fine. I can do type hinting for php fragments `<? ?>` in `.html` files for variables and for `$this` like:

```
<?
/**
* @var $this My_Custom_Class
*/
?>
```

I have some dynamically added properties in `.html` templates, which I don't know how should I instruct PhpStorm to hint. Config file containing associative array is passed to init method and then properties are created like this:

```
public function init($params)
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

It is legacy code, widely used so I don't want to touch it.

I tried:

```
<?
/**
* @property $prop_name My_Custom_Class
*/
?>
```

and variations with `@var`, `$this->prop_name`, `$this['prop_name']` different order but nothing works

I can only declare local var and type hint this

```
<?
/**
* @var My_Custom_Class
*/
$prop_name = $this->prop_name 
?>
```

but it's confusing to have multiple declaration. Is there better way ?

Comment: are you editing .php files? Because it works for me in PHPStorm 2016:  `/** @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface */
            $this->logger->debug($msg, array('Exception', $exception));` . Are your namespaces set correct?

Comment: I do edit php files, don't use namespaces in this code. My phpStorm is 2015 (last without subscription), I just tried your way without namespace, but it didn't work

Comment: @PavelNiedoba What do you mean by *"I have some dynamically added properties in .html templates"* -- please show some better example to clarify this. **But in general:** `@property` can only be used in PHPDoc for a class; `@var` can be used to declare local variable or class property/field.; correct order is `@tag [Type] $name`

Comment: I edited the question, \@var works in classes too, but there's no place for \@property in my scenario, however hinting for $this works

Comment: So .. when you type hinting `$this` .. with `My_Custom_Class` -- 1) is that a custom class  that you can edit? 2) is it different in most cases or the same all the time? If you cannot use `@property` then you cannot typehint your custom properties, unless you make some trick via custom class (for IDE only, which is obviously not a desired way).